# Streaming a webm video from a URL into a C++ windows.h application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm using C++ to make my own windows application. There's a .webm video I'd like to play within this application, but I'd like to play it from a URL, as opposed to loading it in from the same directory that I'd put my .exe in. I'm running Windows 10, and just using Emacs and g++ to write/compile.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? What include's do I need, is it possible, etc.?

Note: the webm video can be converted to mp4 as well.

For clarification, by "windows application", I mean one of these:

```
HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, CLASS_NAME, L"WindowName", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT,  CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

I'd like to keep using this, since I can make a nice, borderless window with it!

Answer (score 1):

This [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/SimplePlay) used [`IMFPMediaPlayer::CreateMediaItemFromURL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfplay/nf-mfplay-imfpmediaplayer-createmediaitemfromurl), You can directly pass the URL to the function [`PlayMediaFile`](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/SimplePlay/winmain.cpp#L452), like:

```
WCHAR uri[] = L"http://dl5.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm";
hr = PlayMediaFile(hwnd, uri);
```

Comment: Did this help? Please feel free to contact me if there is any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use gstreamer with uridecodebin (you need to set uri property). It might be needed to add extra autovideoconvert and/or videoscale element between src and sink.

```
GstElement *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("xvoverlay");
GstElement *src = gst_element_factory_make ("uridecodebin", NULL);
GstElement *sink = gst_element_factory_make ("d3dvideosink", NULL);

g_object_set (G_OBJECT (src), "uri","some_url", NULL);

gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), src, sink, NULL);
gst_element_link (src, sink);
gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle (GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY (sink), (guintptr)hwnd);
GstStateChangeReturn sret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline,
  GST_STATE_PLAYING);
```

If you have gstreamer installed test your setup using:

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri="http://dl5.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" ! d3dvideosink
```

Comment: I've downloaded gstreamer, but I'm not really sure what to include or where the files are, or if I need to put it in $PATH. I'm also not sure where I would put this code. Just in the WndProc?

Comment: @Schmleh You can use example I created here https://github.com/bialasjaroslaw/gstreamer_overlay